# Nesting properties in property grid

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have multiple nesting, like nesting within nesting in the property grid? for example, I want to create an xml file in my program and use it to populate my grid. In the propertyGrid, I want to be able to nest within a nest, so product suite will be expandable/collapsable to show product names one and two and product names one and two will also need to be expandable/collapsable to display a sub product name and date.

Is this possible with property grid? please let me know how i can achieve this.  Thanks in advance

```
<ProductSuite>

<Product NameOne=”Product 1”>

<SubProduct Name=”Sub Product 1” Date = "2004, 12, 09"/>

</Product>

<Product NameTwo=”Product 2”>

<SubProduct Name=”Sub Product 2” Date = "2004, 12, 09"/>

</Product>

</ProductSuite>
```

Comment: You will need to write custom TypeConverters, inherit from ExpandableObjectConverter :)

Comment: Because this was the case i reverted to actually specifying the property types in the class, however i am unable to do multiple nesting. Quite annoying.

Comment: it should be possible to do that still with TypeConverters, you may need to overwrite the GetProperties method and return custom property descriptors with attributes that define the EditorAttribute for a UITypeEditor...

Comment: It must be possible. Have a look at Chart.Series. It has a custom property editor (it's a collection), but within that it seems to be using the standard PropertyGrid. EmptyPointStyle has a couple of nested expanding properties.

Comment: Another way I've seen nested properties is when I put a usercontrol on a form and expose some of the controls on the usercontrol so it's visible in the designer (form->usercontrol->control->properties).

Answer (score -2):

yes you can use nested objects in herichical grids

Comment: sorry what is an hierarchical grid. I need to do this in the propertygrid, is this possible using the peoprty grid?

Comment: And how? -1 for no explanation